# How do I find the value of k to make the equations of a line and a plane be parallel?

Tags: geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

Given the equation of the line $r$:

$r:\frac{x-2}{k}=\frac{y-1}{2}=z$

And the equation of the plane $\alpha$:

$\alpha:3x-ky-z-2=0$

How do I determine $k$ such that the line $r$ and the plane $\alpha$ are parallel?

Comment: Hint: What would be the relation of the plane's normal to a parallel line?

Comment: The dot product of the normal vector and a director vector of the line would be zero

Comment: I'm stuck finding the plane's normal...  I am struggling with the materials given to me by my professor...

Comment: Oooh! Vector n to the plane is: $(3,-k,1)$

Comment: It is $(3, -k, -1)$

Comment: Well, how do I unwind further?

Comment: Do the dot product of this with the direction vector of the line and equate to zero.

Comment: Aha, and a vector for the line is $(k, 2, 1)$

Comment: $3k-2k-1=0 \Leftrightarrow k=1$ 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, @Vectorizer and @Math Lover

So, by the equation of $\alpha$, I know that the normal vector is $(3, - k, - 1)$ and from the equation of $r$, I know that it's director vector is $(k, 2, 1)$

With that said, the dot product of both have to be $=0$, and so:

$3k-2k-1=0 \Leftrightarrow k=1$

I have to study harder!!

Comment: Study smarter, not harder.